# how to update value of "last_dt" col when using"UPDATE" or "INSERT IGNORE INTO ~ ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ~" statement

Tags: python, mysql, sql-update, sql-insert, pymysql

The last_dt column is the last date the data was changed. It is managed differently from the inserted date. Inserted date is managed by create_dt.

I want to change the update date value only when there is a change in the other columns except the update_dt column.

so gpt gave me that

```sql
UPDATE your_table
SET column1 = %s, column2 = %s, column3 = %s, update_date = IF(
    column1 <> %s OR column2 <> %s OR column3 <> %s,
    NOW(), update_date
)
WHERE id = %s
```

But I think this method is a bit odd. I actually tested it and there is an error. It is also possible that I have written the code incorrectly.

Is there any good way? Is the answer provided by gpt the correct way? I think many db admins have solved the same problem. I'm asking because I couldn't find a suitable answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have to use this

```
  `date`    TIMESTAMP      NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```